# Create netplan bridge at Azure Ubuntu

Tags: azure, ubuntu, netplan

My ubuntu18 hosted in Azure cloud.
I tried setup bridge in netplan, but fail.

original 50-cloud-init.yaml

```
    network:
    ethernets:
      eth0:
        dhcp4: true
        addresses:
          - 10.0.20.6/24
        dhcp6: false
        match:
          macaddress: 00:0d:3a:83:44:a1
    version: 2
```

modified 50-cloud-init.yaml

```
network:
    ethernets:
      eth0:
        dhcp4: false
        dhcp6: false
        match:
          macaddress: 00:0d:3a:83:44:a1
    bridges:
      br0:
        interfaces: [eth0]
        dhcp4: true
        addresses:
          - 10.0.20.6/24
    version: 2
```

as result - i lost my network, during restart i saw errors like that:

```
[  134.947548] cloud-init[902]: 2020-05-19 04:33:09,786 - azure.py[ERROR]: Failed to read /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases: [Errno 2] Nosuch file or directory: '/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@heynnema gave me answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241624/create-netplan-bridge-at-azure-ubuntu

copy of answer:
Try this. Keep the exact same spacing, indentation, and no tabs.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 00:0d:3a:83:44:a1
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces:
        - eth0
      macaddress: 00:0d:3a:83:44:a1
```

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

```
sudo netplan apply
```

```
reboot
```